# Minimal generating set of union two isomorphic semigroups

Tags: semigroups, finite-semigroups

Assume that there exists a pair of finite semigroups $S$ and $T$ such that $S\cong T$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the minimal generating sets of $S$ and $T$, respectively.

> - If $X\cup Y$ is a semigroup, then can we say anything about its minimal generating set?

Comment: (1) How do you define the operation on $X \cup Y$ ? (2) There might be several minimal generating sets. What do you mean by *the* minimal generating set ?